# Express-validator's default sanitizer doesn't work when chained

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

I am having trouble using the [`default()` sanitizer from express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization-chain-api.html#defaultdefault_value). When I use it in a chain, such as `body("children").optional().isArray().default([])`, the `default` function doesn't do anything, resulting in `children` being `undefined`. However, if I separate these into two different statements (adding a separate `body("children").default([])` sanitizer instead of chaining it with the others), it works perfectly fine. Here is a minimal reproducable example...

```js
import express from "express";
import { body } from "express-validator";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post(
  "/fails",
  body("children").isArray().optional().default([]),
  (req: express.Request) => {
    console.log(`/fails output: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4)}`);
  }
);

app.post(
  "/works",
  body("children").isArray().optional(),
  body("children").default([]),
  (req: express.Request) => {
    console.log(`/works output: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4)}`);
  }
);

app.listen(3000);
```

...that, used with these libraries...

```
@types/express@4.17.12
express-validator@6.12.0
express@4.17.1
typescript@4.3.4
```

...gives this output:

```
/fails output: {}
/works output: {
    "children": []
}
```

Both `POST` requests had an empty body (I am using Postman to test this).

Why is this happening? I have tried juggling the `optional`, `isArray`, and `default` checks around, with no result. Even though `/works`, well, works, I don't want to duplicate the same `body` statement twice for each optional default value I have in my schema.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When removing `.optional()` from the chain, it works. So this code:

```js
import express from "express";
import { body } from "express-validator";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post(
  "/fails",
  body("children").isArray().default([]),
  (req: express.Request) => {
    console.log(`/fails output: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4)}`);
  }
);

app.post(
  "/works",
  body("children").isArray().optional(),
  body("children").default([]),
  (req: express.Request) => {
    console.log(`/works output: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 4)}`);
  }
);

app.listen(3000);
```

Gives the correct output for both `/fails` and `/works`. However, I have no idea why this happens! Why can't I do `.optional().default([])`? Why isn't this documented? I created a bug report on GitHub [here](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/1057) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `optional` validator just [completely ignores](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions) validation chain if value is `undefined`.

You have to decide whether you need `children` field as a default value `[]` even when it's completely missing in the body. And then remove `optional`. Or you may continue without it and then remove `default`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, I just ended up removing `optional` where it didn't matter if `null`, `undefined`, etc. was passed in and instead used `default`, but when the `default` was `null` then I had to do `.default(null).optional({ nullable: true }).isBoolean()`. Thanks!

Comment: However, I kind of already answered my question below. Thanks for the information and docs page though!